# Sql Server, Select column from table 2 and column from table 1 where no relationship

Tags: sql-server, join, relationship, coalesce, not-exists

please can any one help me get get the correct query?

I have two tables holding title/salutation information. The first, 'Title' holds a definitive list of system / English definitions for title/salutations, and the other 'TitleTranslation' contains translation text where it has been added. The translation data  may be completely or partially missing for any language code, so the default system data must be provided when it is missing.

```
Title
-----
TitleId   INT PK
Name      VARCHAR(12) /* English (en) / system version */

TitleTranslation
----------------
TitleTranslationId    INT PK
TitleId               INT FK
LanguageCode          CHAR(2) /* 2 character ISO code (fr, es, ...) */
Name                  VARCHAR(12)
```

What I require to do for a given parameter which states the LanguageCode, for example 'fr', returns any translated title 'Name' where they exist in the system, or the default english system title 'Name' where they have not. In addition I need to be able to provide a filter on the name.

So far I have this query,

```
DECLARE @LanguageCode CHAR(2);
SELECT  @LanguageCode = 'fr';

DECLARE @NameFilter VARCHAR(12);
SELECT  @NameFilter = 'M';

SELECT          COALESCE([TitleTranslation].[name], [Title].[Name]) [Name]
FROM            [ref].[Title]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ref].[TitleTranslation]
        ON      [ref].[TitleTranslation].[TitleId] = [ref].[Title].[TitleId]
WHERE          ([ref].[TitleTranslation].[LanguageCode] = @LanguageCode
OR              [ref].[TitleTranslation].[LanguageCode] IS NULL)
AND             COALESCE([TitleTranslation].[name], [Title].[Name]) Like '%' + @NameFilter + '%';
```

Is the COALESCE function with an OUTER JOIN the best way to achieve this? Or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: It seems fine to me. in a nutshell - beware of premature optimization.  out of the nutshell - unless you have a good reason, or the query itself doesn't do what you want it to do, don't try to optimize it. if you do want to optimize it, run it through ssms and display it's query plan. the sql itself looks good.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'm not strong on queries that are anything other than standard CRUDs!